# How can I install all dependencies for a specific python package?

Tags: python, pandas, dependencies, package

When I install some python packages, `pandas` for example, I'd like to use the following command:

```
conda install pandas
```

This does install some denpendencies of `pandas`, BUT NOT ALL!

When I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.to_excel('a_excel_file.xlsx')
```

It gives me errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Miniconda\envs\to_be_deleted2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2181, in to_excel
    engine=engine,
  File "D:\Miniconda\envs\to_be_deleted2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 726, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(stringify_path(writer), engine=engine)
  File "D:\Miniconda\envs\to_be_deleted2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 18, in __init__
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "D:\PyCharm Professional 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Looks like `openpyxl` were not installed as the installation of `pandas`. Why that happended? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openpyxl` is an **optional** dependency of `pandas`, this is the reason why it wasn't installed when you installed `pandas`.

`pandas` has many such optional dependencies which add useful, but not core, features - see the [installation documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#optional-dependencies) for a complete list.

Comment: Thanks for post. It seems that the only way to get all requirements is test every function in local environment before deploying in a new one.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a '.txt' file containing the optional dependencies from the list I linked, each on its own line, then install all in one command using `pip install -r DEPENDENCY_FILE.txt`.

Comment: Yeah, I know this trick， using `pip freeze` command to create a requirements file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's too bad that `pandas` doesn't expose these optional dependencies to pip. If so, we could do like `pip install pandas[openpyxl]`.